# Error on starting Salesforce DX project

Tags: salesforcedx, package, unlocked-package

[EDITED]
So, I'm trying to use SalesforceDX to develop. But I keep getting stuck on the configuration. It seems to work fine until I get to the pushing part. I'll post the commands I used.

- Created a Package on my DevHub org called AutomationC;
- CD into the folder
- Went into VS Code and used **sfdx force:project:create -n AutomationProj**
- used **sfdx force:auth:web:login -a DevHub** to authorize the production org
- retrieved the package with **sfdx force:mdapi:retrive -p AutomationC -r ./scrPack**
- extract the files to ./scrPack/AutomationC/*
- converted with **sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r ./srcPck/AutomationC -d ./force-app/main/default**. Althoug the files weren't copied to the force-app structure
- used **sfdx force:org:create -v DevHub -f .config/project-scratch-def.json -a devScratch** to create the scratch org
- tried to push the source with **sfdx force:source:push --json --loglevel fatal -u devScratch**

What followed was a series of errors regarding missing fields or content. I tried using **force:mdapi:deploy** as well and messing with the order inside the package file to set objects and fileds first, no success.

After the comment of @DavidReed I ran convert without the -d flag the files were copied into the force-app structure. but running the push command I'm still getting errors.

[image: The error says the file was not found. but the apex conde is inside force-app/main/default/classes as it should be]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "files weren't copied to the force-app structure" - what did `force:mdapi:convert` do? It sounds like it did not find your MDAPI source code. If nothing was copied to `force-app`, where were the errors located when you ran `sfdx force:source:push`?

Comment: You had a point, I executed, from a clean project, the commands removing the -d flag on the convertion, and it worked. But I still get the error, of non existing objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. I was missing a command, and some flags:

For example, the -d flag, to make the devHub my default org was missing.
Also, the force:source:convert command was not in my list. after that all worked as it should.